# multiple insert multiple Column to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My form format

```
<div>                
    <section>
    <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Display Text" value="Google"/>
    </section>     
    <section>
    <input type="text" name="url[]" placeholder="URL Link" value="http://www.google.com"/>
    </section>
</div> 

<div>               
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Display Text" value="Yahoo"/>
    </section>  
    <section >
        <input type="text" name="url[]" placeholder="URL Link" value="http://www.Yahoo.com"/>
    </section>
</div>
```

full code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sky94132003/rf9obkc9/1/

Mysql Structure

**table_name**

id (PK)

title

url

---

How to save to MySQL would be smarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to a insert multiple values in one insert query, this is how you do it

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (title, url) VALUES";

$data = array_combine($_POST['title'], $_POST['url']);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $sql .= "('$key', '$value'),";
}

$sql = rtrim($sql,',');

echo $sql;
```

output sample

```
 INSERT INTO table_name (title, url) VALUES('Google', 'http://www.google.com'),('Yahoo', 'http://www.Yahoo.com') ... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your array suggest !  I very confuse about array function.

Comment: if you're confused about array_combine see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php it basically combines two arrays into `key => value` pair